# Is the visa-free entry to Schengen region multiple entry or single entry?

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry

I entered Germany in June, it was a visa-free entry (because I have an Australian passport) and I stayed 66 days before exiting to UK.  Can I now return to France and stay 24 more days, or do I need to wait until the 6 month period is finished and 90 days resets?  I'm not sure whether I am entitled to multiple entry or single entry, because of the Visa waiver for Australians all I have is the date and stamp on my passport from Frankfurt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a visa, it's either single-entry or multiple-entry. If you have visa-free entries, it works as if you were getting a new visa each time you cross the border. You can visit multiple times, as long as your [total number of days of presence never goes beyond more than three months in a half-year](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20311/leaving-schengen-region-to-reset-90-days/20315#20315).

Answer (score 1):

This site answer your question: http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=1841750

Look:

> The official rule for the Schengen visa is that, on the day you first
>   enter any country within the Schengen zone, you start a 180 day
>   "period", within which you can stay a maximum of 90 days in all
>   Schengen countries. After you have racked up your 90 days (in one go,
>   or in several chunks if you leave to non-Schengen countries & come
>   back), you can't enter any Schengen country again until your 180
>   period ends. And on day 180, no matter what, you have to leave
>   Schengen territory (even if you haven't used all your 90 days), but
>   you can then turn around & come back in again the next day & get a new
>   90/180 day period. So: if you enter on day 1 & stay for 90 days
>   immediately, you have to leave on day 90 & cannot re-enter any
>   Schengen country until your 180 day "period" is up.

I hope this will be useful to you.

Comment: This doesn't look right: you don't have to leave Schengen on day 180 if you haven't used your 90 days. For example, if you visit Schengen on January 1st just for the day, then come back on June 29, you don't have to leave on June 30, you can stay for three months minus one day. (The [rules](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20311/leaving-schengen-region-to-reset-90-days/20315#20315) say “three months” and “half-year”, not “90 days” and “180 days”, by the way).